# symfony & phpunit : $client->getProfile()->getCollector('db')->getQueryCount() returning always same result

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, profiler

In my tests with phpunit and symfony2, I am trying to assess the query count, following the examples in symfony doc.

For some strange reason, the query count is always the same, whatever the page which is loaded.

Can someone help me figure out why ?

My code :

```
/**
 * @dataProvider urlProvider
 * @param $url
 */
public function testPageIsSuccessful($url)
{
    $client = static::createClient(array(), array(
            'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'superadmin',
            'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => '587010',
        ));
    $client->enableProfiler();
    $client->followRedirects();
    $client->request('GET', $url);
    var_dump($url);
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    $queryCount = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('db')->getQueryCount();
    var_dump('Q: ' . $queryCount);
    $this->assertLessThan(60,$queryCount);
```

}

the previous code is dumping the following, with a constant number of 18 queries (which does not reflect the reality) :

```
.string(44) "/foodanalytics/user_supplier/change_supplier"
string(5) "Q: 18"
.string(10) "/dashboard"
string(5) "Q: 18"
.string(34) "/user/associate/display_associates"
string(5) "Q: 18"
.string(46) "/job/application/display_employer_applications"
string(5) "Q: 18"
...
```

Comment: Did you:

read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/profiling.html and set it up identically?
use the profiler token to have a look inside of those 18 queries to see what they actually do?
How many queries do you expect for the URLs? Is it the case that they are all 18 or is 18 to high for you?